# How can I Preload data using CSV Files in Play Framework

Tags: database, csv, playframework-2.0, preload

My Play Framework project is getting data from a database, but I would prefer to preload the data at the beginning of the application. I have already extracted the database as CSV files, so I would preferably use them to preload the data. But how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Play 2.2 or older, you can put your code inside object Global.scala.

> `object Global extends GlobalSettings {
>   override def onStart(app: Application): Unit = {
>   // place your logic to access CSV here
>   }`

This is the first method to run on your application start. This should do your work.